# Object appear in Redux DevTools but empty in console.log

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux

I have a problem with redux Devtools and console.log().

I can see my object in Redux DevTools :
https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/18/6/1557004256-capture-d-ecran-du-2019-05-04-22-10-33.png

and my console.log empty in top :
https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/18/6/1557004421-capture-d-ecran-du-2019-05-04-23-00-50.png

my code in render :

```
    const { user, users } = this.props;
    console.log(users)
```

my dispatch :

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(userActions.getAll());
  }
```

my mapStateToProps (not ES6):

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { authentication, users } = state;
  const { user } = authentication;
  return {
    user,
    users,
  };
}
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: This doesnt seem like an issue. It sounds like you're trying to console.log something from your store before your component connects to it. Where are you calling the console.log()?

Comment: @ChristopherNgo in render